# How to determine what modules are missing

Tags: 10.10

I got an "FATAL ERROR: Could not find /lib/modules/2.6.35-25-generic: file not found" or something like this when booting. The system appears to be stable, but this message is annoying.

How can I see what modules is missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/642421) and only a cosmetic problem. Don't worry about it!